# UserControl with datatemplated ContentControl throws binding errors when its DataContext changes

Tags: c#, wpf

In my project, I wanted a `UserControl` that can display different formats of an image (bitmap, svg), selected from a `ListBox`. The `SelectedItem` of the `ListBox` is bound to the appropriate view model, which in turn changes the `DataContext` of the `UserControl`, and what I want to achieve is for it to change the displaying control (an `Image` for bitmaps, a `SharpVectors.SvgViewBox` for svg files) through data templates. It does so, but raises data binding errors, as if the templates were still intact whilst the `UserControl`'s `DataContext` has already been changed.

I should like to a) avoid any data binding errors even if they cause no visible problems b) understand what is happening, so I prepared a MWE, which, to my surprise, displays the same behaviour, so I can present it here.

My minimal `UserControl` is as follows:

```
<UserControl x:Class="BindingDataTemplateMWE.VersatileControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type system:String}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content.Length, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContentControl}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type system:DateTime}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content.DayOfWeek, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContentControl}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl
                Content="{Binding .}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The `MainWindow` that references this `UserControl` has the following XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="BindingDataTemplateMWE.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BindingDataTemplateMWE"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListBox
            Grid.Column="0"
            SelectedItem="{Binding Selected}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
        <local:VersatileControl
            Grid.Column="1"
            DataContext="{Binding Selected}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

with the following code-behind (to make the MWE indeed minimal, I made the window its own `DataContext`, but originally there is a dedicated view model):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace BindingDataTemplateMWE
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private object selected;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public List<object> Items { get; }

        public object Selected {
            get { return selected; }
            set {
                selected = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Selected)));
            }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            Items = new List<object>() { "a string", DateTime.Now, "another string" };
        }
    }
}
```

When I select a different item in the list, the desired effect takes place: the `UserControl` displays the length if a `string` is selected and the day of week when a `DateTime`. Still, I get the following binding error when selecting a `DateTime` after a `string`:

> Length property not found on object of type DateTime.

and conversely, selecting a `string` after a `DateTime` yields

> DayOfWeek property not found on object of type String.

It is clear that what I am doing is not meant to be done, but I do not know what the correct paradigm is and what happens in the background. Please advise me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this problem often when creating complex data templates (several levels of nesting) when views are loaded/unloaded. Honestly, some of such errors I am ignoring completely.

In your case something similar happens because you are manipulating `DataContext` directly. At the moment the new value is set, the previous value is still used in bindings, which monitor for source change and will try to update the target.

In your scenario you don't need this constant monitoring, so an easy fix is to use [BindingMode.OneTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingmode):

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type system:String}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content.Length, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}, Mode=OneTime}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: I still do not understand the conceptual difference between the cases, but in one control setting `BindingMode.OneTime` works, whilst in another it prevents the changes from taking effect. So I ended up with dropping `BindingMode.OneTime`, leaving the `ContentControl` empty in XAML and simulating a `DataTemplateSelector` in code-behind. The trick is to circumvent WPF's hidden mechanisms and handling the `DataContextChanged` event of the `UserControl`, set the `ContentTemplate` first and **then** the `Content`.